# Firebase - Invalid path: Invalid token in path

Tags: firebase

I'm using this PHP package, [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php), to communicate with the REST API.

I want to do very basic data push:

```
require_once ('utilities/firebase/firebaseLib.php');

$firebase = new Firebase(<my firebase url>, <my firebase token>);

$data = [
    'ip' => "123456789",
    'session' => "1234",
    'sequence' => "12",
    'time' => "159159159",
    'event' => "Pause",
    'data' => "1"
];

$res = $firebase->push(<my firbase path.json>, $data);
```

After execution I get this error: { "error" : "Invalid path: Invalid token in path" }

Not sure what this error means, no explanation at the docs...

Will be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 5):

The firebase path in the `push` method (`$res = $firebase->push(my-firebase.firebaseio.com/structure/of/json, $data);` should be the relative path to the main firebase url.

So instead of `'my-firebase.firebaseio.com/structure/of/json'` it should be just `'structure/of/json'`.